# How to find the name and coordinates of the place we are nearby?

Tags: flutter, google-maps, geolocation, google-geolocation

In Flutter what is the most correct method to find the name and coordinates of the place we are inside now using Google Maps or Google Geolocation API?

`searchNearbyWithRadius()` seems to be such a method, but Java has [`PlacesClient.findCurrentPlace`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/android-sdk/reference/com/google/android/libraries/places/api/net/PlacesClient#findCurrentPlace(com.google.android.libraries.places.api.net.FindCurrentPlaceRequest)) that seems more stereotypic for this task than `searchNearbyWithRadius()`. Is such a method available in Flutter (or at least in the REST API)? Please show a reference.

Comment: Maybe as described in https://medium.com/@fernnandoptr/how-to-get-users-current-location-address-in-flutter-geolocator-geocoding-be563ad6f66a ?

Comment: @RandalSchwartz This method has the deficiency that it does not return `placeId` (a unique has identifying an object at Google Maps). So, I can't use this method.